# Can I automatically change the dataset for a tablix based on the current month?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I have a report with 7 datasets and 7 tables **all exactly the same** except the datasets each have a slightly different where clause

```
where datepart(DW,[Start Time]) = 2
```

The idea is to show data for each monday this month in one table and each tuesday in another and so on. So one table uses the monday dataset (above) one uses

```
where datepart(DW,[Start Time]) = 3
```

for tuesday and so on. What I really want to do is have the report decide which dataset to use first based on what day the first of the current month was. So this month (April) the 1st was a saturday so I'd like my leftmost table to use the dataset

```
where datepart(DW,[Start Time]) = 7
```

Then the one after it to be sunday and so on. But next month (May) I want it to automatically switch to using the monday dataset in the first table as the 1st will be a monday.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use a sub-report that uses a single dataset. This dataset would have a where clause that takes a parameter

```
WHERE DATEPART(DW, [Start Time]) = @dayOfWeek
```

Replace your current 7 tables with 7 copies of the same sub-report but change the parameters to be based on the first day of the month so you first sub-report would have the parameter passed as

```
=WeekDay(dateserial(Year(now()), Month(now()), "1"))
```

the second sub report would have the parameter passed as

```
=WeekDay(dateserial(Year(now()), Month(now()), "2"))
```

and so on...

Comment: This is super clever and really helped me understand the true power of parameters. I feel like I should go back and rewrite all my old reports to make them all dynamically generated.

Comment: Glad to help, I usually think to myself, if I'm doing something repetitive, then I'm probably going about this the wrong way....